# Cannot insert content of dataframe to partitioned parquet-formatted hive table

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert the content of a dataframe to a partitioned parquet-formatted hive table using

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(myTable)

with hive.exec.dynamic.partition = 'true'  and hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = 'nonstrict'.

I keep getting an parquet.io.ParquetEncodingException saying that

"empty fields are illegal, the field should be ommited completely instead".

The schema includes arrays, and the df do contain some empty entries for these fields.

However, when I insert the df content into a non-partitioned table, I do not get an error.

Can anyone give me an explanation about what is going on here ? Why does this error appear only when the hive table is partitioned ?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Spark you are using ?

Comment: I using Spark 2.1.0 on yarn